# How to get headers from within Exchange object in the body object

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have headers i'm setting within a function and then saving the Exchange objects to a list.
`` newExchange.`in`.setHeader("aggregationCount", 3) ``

Im then trying to retrieve this header later on and I can see it, in the object its in the path of `Exchange.in.body.in.headers` - How would I access this variable, I've tried `` (e.`in`.getHeader("aggregationCount") `` however this doesn't work. All i need to is to pass a variable/property through on the Exchange object, if there is other ways to do this, tell me and i can just use this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Camel route, you can simply use .header("HeaderName") to return the header value. In this case, something like:

```
.header("aggregationCount")
```

Or if you need to use the value in a conditional:

```
.when(header("aggregationCount").isGreaterThan(0))
```

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/header-language.html

To answer your other question, you could also use exchangeProperty to store and retrieve values.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/languages/exchangeProperty-language.html

Comment: My problem was it was an exchange inside of an exchange, and i needed to parse the body as an exchange to get the headers inside of it. If i didnt make this dumb mistake, obviously this would be the answer. Thanks!